# How to Trigger a Widget Refresh in the WordPress Customizer

Tags: wordpress

I have a widget where dynamic input fields are being inserted by javascript. Also, these fields can be sorted, and moved around.

The combination of these two things causes the Customizer "change" trigger for the widget not to fire, and therefore there is no selective refresh for the preview page.

Is there a way I can tell wp.customize to "re-listen" to all the input fields for a change event after a sort? And also, is there a way to manually fire a selective refresh in wp.customize after I change the sorting order inside a widget?

Changing the sorting order does not cause any input fields to change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: It is either that, or you might want to look into [mcve] to give some ideas how to improve your question.